# Why my object type in my doctrine2 entity doesn't get updated when calling persist() & flush()?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Here is what I'm doing:

```
    $entity = new Meta();
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->foo = 15;
    $obj->bar = 0;
    $obj->bor = true;
    $entity->setObject($obj);
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

    $entity = $entityRepository->find(1);
    var_dump($entity);
```

returns:

```
object(Jo\Model\Entity)[130]
  protected 'id' => int 1
  protected 'user' => null
  protected 'object' => 
    object(stdClass)[105]
      public 'foo' => int 15
      public 'bar' => int 0
      public 'bor' => boolean true

    $entity->getObject()->bar = 9;
    var_dump($entity);
```

returns:

```
object(Jo\Model\Entity)[130]
  protected 'id' => int 1
  protected 'user' => null
  protected 'object' => 
    object(stdClass)[105]
      public 'foo' => int 15
      public 'bar' => int 9
      public 'bor' => boolean true
```

!

```
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
```

But after flush the entity is not updated in the database.

Maybe it is because I'm setting the new object from the getObject() method and it has something to do with references or so, but I don't understand then why the second var_dump() shows the correct values in the object.

The getter is pretty simple and just consist in returning the private property.

Any ideas, I'd like to understand this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wasn't sure about this behavior myself but I was curious, so I talked about this shortly on IRC with Jonathan Wage, one of the Doctrine devs.

According to Jon, the reason for this behavior is that when you map an object directly to a property, like you're doing, you must clone to object - in other words, you need a new instance.

When checking if your data has changed, D2 checks whether the object is the same as the old one. It basically just does a x === y type comparison, so unless you have a *completely new instance* it will not recognize the data as changed.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for your answer, I guessed it has something to do with the entity state, however it's not handy